# Improve a diagram using smartdiagram package

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

I want to draw the following diagram better using smartdiagram package.

I got stuck in the following:

1. Rotate the diagram so the circle of **Social Goals** to at 12 o'clock position.
2. Add the words **Socio-efficiency**, **Eco-justice** and **Eco-efficiency**

I am open to any new ideas or improvements to the diagram.

Original Diagram
[image]

My version of the diagram
[image]

My Code

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60,magenta!60,
            blue!50!cyan},planet size=4cm,bubble node size=3cm,bubble center node size=4.5cm}
            \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
            Sustainable\\Development,Social\\Goals,Economic\\Goals,Environmental\\Goals
            }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please extend your code to a full but minimal example. Then it is easier for others to copy and test the code without having to add stuff to it.

Comment: Right: the code snippet doesn't pass the copy&compile test ...

Comment: OMG. I am so sorry. My bad. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier to do it with pure `TiKZ` than trying to modify `smartdiagram`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, minimum size=4.5cm, draw opacity=1, fill opacity=0.5, fill=gray!70, text width=2cm, align=center]{Sustainable Development};
    \node[circle, minimum size=3cm, draw opacity=1, fill opacity=0.5, fill=orange!50, text width=2cm, align=center, draw=white, line width=2pt] at (90:3cm) {Social\\ Goals};
    \node[circle, minimum size=3cm, draw opacity=1, fill opacity=0.5, fill=green!70, text width=2cm, align=center, draw=white, line width=2pt] at (210:3cm) {Economic\\ Goals};
    \node[circle, minimum size=3cm, draw opacity=1, fill opacity=0.5, fill=red!70, text width=2cm, align=center, draw=white, line width=2pt] at (-30:3cm) {Environmental\\ Goals};
    \node[text width=2cm, align=center] at (30:3.5cm) {Eco-justice};
    \node[text width=2cm, align=center] at (150:3.5cm) {Socio-efficiency};
    \node[text width=2cm, align=center] at (270:3.5cm) {Eco-efficiency};
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{document}
```

[image]